# Not identifying all the datatypes

Tags: python, hadoop

Not able to differentiate the datatypes while I am doing the profiling for csv file, Giving every filed as string only

I have tried the below code

```
rdd = sc.textFile(file)
header = rdd.first()
rdd = rdd.filter(lambda x: x != header)
rdd1 = rdd.mapPartitions(lambda x: csv.reader(x))
spark_df = rdd1.toDF(header.split(','))
```

After done the profiling for the CSV file, I am getting all the fileds are strings only, not able to identify as numeric, date

Comment: But, are you able to transform them after loading? Can you give a reproducible example?

Comment: I have many files, I can't do for every field each time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595893/read-csv-as-data-frame-in-spark-1-6 maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The function `textFile()` does not support schema inference.
If you are reading from a structured source (such as csv), use `sc.read.csv` instead, which supports schema inference.
Your code would be:

```
df = sc.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").csv(file)
```

Comment: I am using the spark older version 1.6, so I can't use that code.

Comment: Oh, then you should use [DataFrameReader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader)